dist directory "invisible" to the go server process inside docker
I have a go server written in Gin, which serves a react application from the dist directory on the root path. The path of the dist directory is passed via environment variables, and this code works fine on my machine (it renders the react app successfully). However when I run this inside a docker container, the /api endpoints work as expected but the root path always gives a 404 not found error.
func main() {
    db := initDB()
    defer db.Close()

    gin.SetMode(GIN_MODE)
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))

    apiRouter := router.Group("/api")
    v1Router := apiRouter.Group("/v1")

    misc.RegisterRoutes(v1Router)
    pastesHandler := pastes.NewHandler(db)
    pastesHandler.RegisterRoutes(v1Router)

    router.NoRoute(gin.WrapH(http.FileServer(http.Dir(DIST_DIR))))

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":" + PORT,
        Handler:        router,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20, // 1MB
    }


    log.Print("PWD")
    log.Println(os.Getwd())
    log.Println(os.ReadDir("."))
    log.Println("DIST_DIR", DIST_DIR)
    log.Println(os.ReadDir(DIST_DIR))
    log.Println("Listening at port", PORT)
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}

Here's the server output:
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 PWD
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 /app <nil>
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 [- .env d dist/ - server] <nil>
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 DIST_DIR "/app/dist"
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 [] open "/app/dist": no such file or directory
pasteforge-1  | 2024/08/04 16:06:55 Listening at port 8080

Dockerfile:
FROM node:22-slim AS frontend-build

ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
WORKDIR /app

# Build the frontend
COPY "package.json" "pnpm-lock.yaml" ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN pnpm run build


# build the backend
FROM golang:1.22-alpine AS server-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY "./backend/go.sum" .
COPY "./backend/go.mod" .
RUN go mod download
COPY backend/ .
RUN go build -o server


# Final stage: Copy the frontend and Go server into a new image
FROM alpine:3.20
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=frontend-build /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=server-build /app/server .
COPY --from=server-build /app/.env ./.env
ENV ADDR="0.0.0.0"
ENV PORT=8080
ENV GIN_MODE=release
ENV DIST_DIR="/app/dist"
# Expose the port your Go server listens on
EXPOSE 8080
USER root
CMD ["./server"]

I've already checked the passed environment variables inside the docker container, and verified that the dist directory exists within the container and that the server process is running as root.
I've also tried both absolute and relative paths to the dist directory.
Here's the output of ls -lR from inside the container: https://pastebin.com/nuzPafyr

My first guess here is that the double quotes in ENV DIST_DIR="..." are being retained; that would be consistent with your output and the error.  (Note that this is contrary to the ENV documentation, though.)  Can you tell whether the variable is /app/dist or "/app/dist"?

oh my god. I can't believe the problem I've been pulling my hair over for the last 2 days was this insignificant. Thanks a ton, David Maze. The actual issue was I was running the containers via docker-compose and the DIST_DIR env variable was also being set there, with quotation marks. Removing them worked. Again, thanks a lot.
